# How to find the closed form for $\sum_{i=1}^k 3^{-i}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

How do I calculate (is closed form the correct word?) the closed form of:
$$\sum_{i=1}^k 3^{-i}?$$
I know how to calculate the geometric series:
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty 3^{-i} = \frac1{1-(1/3)}$$
But that doesn't help since I don't know how to calculate $\sum_{i=k+1}^\infty 3^{-i}$ (without calculating the thing I want). Wolframalpha says it is $$\sum_{i=1}^k 3^{-i}=\frac12 - \frac{3^{-k}}{2}$$
But I don't know how they calculated this. Maybe there is a closed form for
$$\sum_{i=1}^k n^{-i},$$
for $n\in \Bbb N$?

Comment: Do you actually know how to _calculate_ $\sum_1^\infty$? Or do you just know the answer? If you actually know how to calculate $\sum_1^\infty$ the same calculation can be used for $\sum_1^k$.

Comment: Oh no, I got downvotes :(. I tried hard to typeset this

Comment: The typesetting is fine - the problem is you could have easily found the answer here or elsewhere. If you google "geometric series" the first  hit answers your question: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series

Comment: Your $\sum_{i=1}^\infty 3^{-i} = \frac1{1-(1/3)}$ is wrong. It should be either

$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty 3^{-i} = \frac1{1-(1/3)}$$
or

$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty 3^{-i} = \frac{(1/3)}{1-(1/3)}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$S_k = (1/3)^1+(1/3)^2+....+(1/3)^k$;

$(1/3)S_k= (1/3)^2+.....+(1/3)^{k+1}$;

Subtract:

$S_k-(1/3)S_k=$

$(2/3)S_k=(1/3)^1-(1/3)^{k+1}$;

$S_k=(3/2)((1/3)-(1/3)(1/3)^k)$;

$S_k =(1/2)-(1/2)(1/3)^k$;

$S_k= (1/2)-(1/2)3^{-k}.$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use the well-known formula $$\sum_{i=1}^n q^i=\frac{q^{n+1}-q}{q-1}$$ for $q\ne 1$

Answer (score 0):

If you know about the infinite geometric series sum (for $-1\le r<1$)

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} r^i = \frac{r}{1-r}$$

Then a finite sum is just

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{k} r^i &= \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} r^i - \sum_{i=k+1}^{\infty} r^i\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} r^i - r^k\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} r^i\\
&= \frac{r(1-r^k)}{1-r}
\end{align*}$$

(This formula works for all $r\ne 1$, but this proof only works for $-1\le r<1$.)

Answer (score 0):

we have:
$$S_k=\sum_{i=1}^k3^{-i}$$
note that the terms of a geometric series can be expressed as:
$$a_k=ar^{k-1}$$
in this case, we have: $a=\frac 13$,$r=\frac 13$. We can now use the formula:
$$S_k=a\frac{(1-r^k)}{1-r}$$
this should give you:
$$S_k=\frac{1}{2}\left(1-3^{-k}\right)$$
It can also be derived as given below

---

we have:
$$S_k=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3^2}+...\frac{1}{3^k}$$
which can be factorised to:
$$S_k=\frac{1}{3}\left(1+\frac{1}{3}+...\frac{1}{3^{k-1}}\right)$$
and notice that this is just the same as:
$$S_k=\frac 13\left(1+S_{k-1}\right)$$
we also know that:
$$S_k=S_{k-1}+a_k=S_{k-1}+\frac{1}{3^k}\Rightarrow S_{k-1}=S_k-\frac{1}{3^k}$$
substituting one equation into the other, we get:
$$3S_k=1+S_k-\frac{1}{3^k}$$
$$2S_k=1-\frac{1}{3^k}\Rightarrow S_k=\frac 12\left(1-3^{-k}\right)$$